# Import Issue CSV via DuckDB

Tags: csv, odbc, powerquery, duckdb

I want to import several CSV files in Power Query using the DuckDB ODBC Driver. However, I get an error named: "DataSource.Error: An error occurred but no ODBC error information was available."

I get this error at a very specific line, so I assumed it has to do with an encoding error, but I checked the encoding type, which is UTF-8 and should be readable.

My connection string: database=:memory:;encoding=65001;quotestyle=QuoteStyle.Csv
I also tried:
database=:memory:
database=:memory:;quotestyle=QuoteStyle.Csv

When I load the same CSV file directly, I don't get any errors in this case. But I rather do it via DuckDB ODBC Driver, because I have  multiple CSV files and then I only have to maintain 1 gateway.

Any thoughts or advice?

Comment: Did you set up a trace file in `odbcinst.ini`? If so have you looked to see what is reported there?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, haven't done that, how can i set that up?

Comment: It's going to depend on your OS. Read the instruction here [DuckDB ODBC](https://duckdb.org/docs/api/odbc/overview)